# Django admin: TypeError on any post request

Tags: python, django

I created a new Django (v. 1.11) project and using `python manage.py createsuperuser` I created a user. I can log in to the admin section on `localhost:8888/admin` with this user account. However, I cannot do anything else: **whenever I trigger a POST request** other than the login page, **I get the following error:**

> ## TypeError at /admin/...
>
> `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

("..." can be replaced for example by `auth/group/add/`), but this behavior is general, not specific to this request

The following traceback suggests problem with parsing the CSRF token from the page, but I didn't have such issues on other pages within my application apart from admin.

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  178.             response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in process_view
  298.                     request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py" in _get_post
  126.             self._load_post_and_files()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in _load_post_and_files
  299.                 self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in parse_file_upload
  258.         return parser.parse()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py" in parse
  198.                         data = field_stream.read(size=read_size)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py" in read
  369.         out = b''.join(parts())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py" in parts
  364.                     emitting = chunk[:remaining]

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/group/add/
Exception Value: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some relevant code which might trigger this error, like any custom user model or some code in some apps admin file

Comment: The problem is within the file uploads code, not the csrftoken (the file uploads code call is triggered on the first access to `request.POST`, which happens to be the csrftoken verification).  The first thing I'd do would be to uninstall then reinstall django - preferably using a virtualenv this time. If the problem persists, I'd edit django/http/multipartparser.py to add a pdb breakpoint just before the offending line (line 364 in your traceback) and check what happens (and specially what `remaining` actually is at this point and why it's not what it's supposed to be).  Basic debugging really

Comment: @Exprator there's no custom user model nor code in apps' admin files. Vanilla Django project with no bells and whistles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the problem.

For the future reference, the problem was the key `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` in the project settings having a floating point value (`10e6` is an easy-to-overlook float in Python). It has to be an integer.

Comment: oh god thank you so much, I had exactly this issue after using a float value (`10e6` exactly!) for `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`

Comment: Your answer is great. I was using `1024 ** 2 * 0.5` and that was producing `524288.0` (a float). Now I wrap the result with `int(...)` and it works!

Comment: You are a saviour, and thank you so much for posting the stack trace because the only reason I found this was on my 50th search that matched `django/http/multipartparser.py, line 460, in parts`. The error itself is too common that any combination I tried with `admin` around it did not end up with anything useful. I will look if I can contribute a PR to type check this when the settings are checked - the app should not be allowed to start if a float cannot be handled at all. At the very least a better error message would be very useful too.